# Dojo dojo.rawXhrPost and dojo.xhrPost

Tags: json, dojo

My question is: can we use dojo.xhrPost to post some Json data? More detail:

I have been experimenting with Dojo code to POST JSON data to a RESTful service. It seems to be that the behaviours of **dojo.xhrPost** and **dojo.rawXhrPost** are different, or to be more accurate rawXhrPost() works and xhrPost() does not. This is not consistent with my reading of the [docs](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/rawXhrPost)

> The original purpose of
>   dojo.rawXhrPost was a method that
>   could be used to send a raw post body
>   to the server. As of 1.3, this
>   function is common with
>   dojo.xhrPost(). So, for usage of
>   dojo.rawXhrPost(), see dojo.xhrPost()

Which implies that xhrPost() is enough. My code looks like this - I've got a "toy" library service that manages Editions of Books. The code wants to POST a new entry,

```
        var myEdition = {"Edition":{"isbn":"44"}};

        var xhrArgs = {
            url: "http://localhost:8081/LibraryWink/library/editions",
            postData: dojo.toJson(myEdition),
            handleAs: "json",
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},

            load: function(data) {
                dojo.byId("mainMessageText").innerHTML = "Message posted.";
            },
            error: function(error) {

                dojo.byId("mainMessageText").innerHTML = "Error :" + error;
            }
        };

        var deferred = dojo.rawXhrPost(xhrArgs);
```

The *headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"}* part in necessary so that my JAX-RC service understands that the content is JSON.

What I find is that the code above works perfectly. However if instead I say:

```
var deferred = dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
```

No data is transmitted in the POST. I have a TCP/IP monitor in place and can see that there is nothing transmitted.

So, is this a bug, or am I driving xhrPost() incorrectly? Or should I use rawXhrPost()? If the latter, under what circumstances do we use the two flavours of XhrPost?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As of DOJO 1.4 the this should work:

```
var myEdition = {"Edition":{"isbn":"44"}};

var xhrArgs = {
    url: "http://localhost:8081/LibraryWink/library/editions",
    postData: dojo.toJson(myEdition),
    handleAs: "json",
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json"},
    load: function(data) {
        dojo.byId("mainMessageText").innerHTML = "Message posted.";
    },
    error: function(error) {

        dojo.byId("mainMessageText").innerHTML = "Error :" + error;
    }
};

dojo.xhrPost(xhrArgs);
```

If you are posting JSON data, the Content-Type header is critical. If you don't add it, the browser will default to 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' and URL encode your data for you.

You may want to add a charset to the Content-Type header (I do this) but that does not stop it from functioning:

```
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"}
```

On Firefox 3.6 at least, the charset is automatically added.

As Dom mentions, the HTTP PUT equivalent is dojo.xhrPut. The difference here is that you need to add your request body data as putData instead of postData.

Comment: Thanks, will experiment and report back.

Comment: I think the charset you meant to use is utf-8 not uft-8.

Answer (score 3):

While using Dojo library from http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.3/dojo/dojo.xd.js, I've no issue posting data from a form (data serialized by `dojo.formToJson()`).

```
dojo.xhrPut({
    putData: dojo.formToJson("locationInformation"),
    handleAs: "json",
    load: function(response, ioArgs) {
        // ... business logic ...
    },
    error: function(message, ioArgs) { alert(message+"\nurl: "+ioArgs.url); },
    url: "/API/Location"
});
```

Using Firebug in Firefox, I can see that my request is built as expected:

- Among other request headers: `Content-Type = application/json; charset=UTF-8`
- Body of the Put request: `{"postalCode":"h8p3r8","countryCode":"CA"}`

xhrPost/xhrPut seem to work as rawXhrPost/rawXhrPut...

Comment: Please could you clarify - your code is using xhrPut(), have you also tried it with xhrPost() ?

Comment: xhrPost() and data passed with the "postData" parameter works as xhrPut() and the "putData" parameter...

Answer (score 2):

One more thing that I would like to add the the answer. When working with AJAX apps, it's also a good idea to set the Accept value to application/json when that's what you're expecting.

```
headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept" : "application/json"}
```